# Scrapy won't select embed elements

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to actually know if there is any flash content in a website.
I use the following code:

```
hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

(len(hxs.select('//embed[contains(@src,".swf")]')) > 0 or len(hxs.select('//object[contains(@data,".swf")]')) > 0  or len(hxs.select('//object/param[contains(@value,".swf")]')) > 0)
```

but always return false.
I realised that even if I use

```
 hxs.select('//embed')
```

it won't select any element when I'm sure there is in the website.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the elements are present before executing JS code?

Comment: Show us the XML you're targeting

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the embed element is present after executing some JS code. I tried running scrapy shell on a youtube video and faced the same issue as you. You can get around this issue by using a library that actually executes JS code such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). Here is some sample code you can use within your normal scrapy spiders.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_44G-kE8lE') # Load page
time.sleep(3) # Make sure we had enough time to load everything
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//embed")
```

After running the last line of code I do see an element whereas with the scrapy hxs I didn't. If you do end up using this solution [this snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/66998/rendered-javascript-crawler-with-scrapy-and-selenium-rc/) for integrating Selenium with scrapy should be helpful.